# Taking very large screenshot from scene

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, opengl-4

I want to take very large screenshots from my application in OpenGL like 20000x20000 for printing on the banner. First of all, I am not able to create such big framebuffers because of the maximum GPU texture size limitation. Anyone can help me how to capture the framebuffer in different chunks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noted, capturing it in multiple passes is the way to go. In the simplest form, you can use multiple passes, each rendering a part of the scene.

To get the properr image sub-region, all you need to do is applying another transformation to the clip-space positions of your vertices. This boils down to simple translations and scalings in `x` and `y`:

When considering the euclidiean *interpretation* of the clip space - the normalized device space - the viewing volume is represented by a cube [-1,1] in all 3 dimensions.

To render only an axis-aligned sub-region of that cube, we have to upscale it so that only the sub-region fits into the [-1,1] area, and we have to translate it properly.

Assuming we want to divide the image into an uniform grid of `m` times `n` tiles, we could do the following transformations when rendering tile `i`,`j`:

1. Move the bottom left of the tile to the origin. That tile position will be at `(-1 + 2*i/m, -1 + 2*j/n)`, so we have to translate with the negated value:

   `x' = x + 1 - 2*i/m`,
   `y' = y + 1 - 2*j/n`

   This is only a helper step to make the final translation  easier.
2. Scale by factors `m` and `n` along x and y directions:

   `x'' = m * x' = x * m + m - 2*i`,
   `y'' = y' * n = y * n + n - 2*j`
3. The tile is now aligned such that it's bottom left corner is (still) at the origin and the upper right center is at (2,2), so just translate it back with `(-1, -1)` so that we end up in the view voulme again:

   `x''' = x'' - 1 = x * m + m - 2*i - 1`,
   `y''' = y'' - 1 = y * n + n - 2*j - 1`

This can of coure be represented as simple affine transformation matrix:

```
(  m     0     0   m - 2*i - 1)
(  0     n     0   n - 2*j - 1)
(  0     0     1        0     )
(  0     0     0        1     )
```

In most cases, you can simply pre-multiply that matrix to the projection-matrix (or whatever matrices you use), and won't have to change anything else during rendering.